# css select all descendants (asterisk) of elements with a class

Tags: css, selector

I want to select all descendant elements of the element with class="x" this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    .x * {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  a
  <p>
    b
     <p class="x">
        c
        <p> should be red </p> foo
     </p>
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

which unfortunately does not apply to those elements. neither `*.x *` does.

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have a `<p>` in a `<p>`. Try changing your inner `<p>` tag to a `<span>` tag.

Hope this helps

Comment: you're right, but w3 validator did not told me so :-/ 
changing p's to div's works now. thanks

Answer (score 4):

<s>I know this is old but the answer is: `.x, .x +* { }`</s>

ETA: I misread the question. The answer is: `.x ~ * { }`